# How to create File Share in azure resource manager template itself?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to automate deployment process of Moodle(https://moodle.org/) using ARM template.
Now, i have used Azure CLI commands for creating File Share in Azure Storage Account, But, is there any way to specify file share within the template itself?

Comment: I think you cannot create NFS-Fileshare on Azure via template at the moment. Or did you find a way?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for that ?